# R: polygons' id different than @data id after load from shapefile

Tags: shapefile, r

I loaded a shapefile in R using readOGR and I named as `data.map`.

I can see the shape pretty well by using

```
plot(data.map)
```

The issue is that polygons' id (the id of the plot) is not the same with the @data id. What I mean is that, when I run:

```
plot(data.map[2, ]) 
data.map@data[2, ]
```

the polygon 2 that is drawed in the plot, is not the one that the data row  2 refers to.

Comment: provide us your data so that we can check... if the issue is to visualise the data of the object you see (plot), try `data.map[2, ]@data`.

Comment: The two things in your question (and the third thing in @BrunoConteLeite comment) should all be the same. If not then something weird is going on and we have no chance of explaining it without a reproducible example. My only hunch is maybe what you think is the "id" is not the row number. Does your data have a column named "id"?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
The problem was that I performed a merge function in the @data part of my spatialpolygonsdataframe but without adding the all.x = TRUE property. As a result, the rows that did not have corresponding rows were eliminated and the ids were messed.

Comment: If you've discovered where you went wrong it can be useful to explain that in your answer. Show how the ids (are they attributes?) were "messed up". If that might happen to other people then you are helping.

Comment: just added the explanation.